# Web Forms 4.5 - Repeater.Items is empty on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback, repeater

I have a Repeater which has it's data set up on Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                 myRepeater.DataSource = data;
                 myRepeater.DataBind();
             }
}
```

When I come to save my data on postback, myRepeater.Items contains zero elements when I know there are several.

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

        ....
        // why does this contain zero elements>
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in myRepeater.Items)
        {
```

Any suggestions as to what may be the issue?

Comment: The code you add is not complete to help you. You can try to add more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, binding the repeater even on postback fixed the issue

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

                 myRepeater.DataSource = data;
                 myRepeater.DataBind();

}
```